# Mount SMB Share

Tags: debian, samba, smb

I am trying to mount an SMB share in Debian that is hosted on Server 2019 so that I can run a nightly bash script and copy some data over to it.  Its been working well until we turned off SMB V1.0 for security reasons.

I have tried different permutations of the command but no matter what i do always get the same thing "mount error(13): Permission denied"

here are some variations of the command that i've been trying

```
mount -t cifs /192.168.1.247/share /media/mnt/testsmb --verbose -o \
vers=2.0,sec=ntlmv2,username=domainuser,password=userpassword,domain=addomain.local

mount -t cifs /192.168.1.247/share /media/mnt/testsmb --verbose -o \
vers=2.0,sec=ntlm,username=domainuser,password=userpassword,domain=addomain.local

mount -t cifs /192.168.1.247/share /media/mnt/testsmb --verbose -o \
vers=3.0,sec=ntlmv2,username=domainuser,password=userpassword,domain=addomain.local

mount -t cifs /192.168.1.247/share /media/mnt/testsmb --verbose -o \
vers=3.0,sec=ntlmssp,username=domainuser,password=userpassword,domain=addomain.local

mount -t cifs /192.168.1.247/share /media/mnt/testsmb --verbose -o \
vers=2.0,sec=ntlmssp,username=domainuser,password=userpassword,domain=addomain.local
```

you get the idea, basically trying different combinations of smb versions and ntlm

i ran wireshark and i see that its giving a couple of errors

```
Error: STATUS_MORE_PROCESSING_REQUIRED
Error: STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
```

i know that the username and password is correct, so i'm not really sure what to do at this point as turning smb v1.0 back on isn't an option.

Comment: Is there any relevant output coming from `--verbose` that could hint at what the problem is?

Comment: Not that I can tell.  I'm actually a little surprised about how non-verbose --verbose is.  It outputs

----BEGIN VERBOSE OUTPUT-----
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=192.168.1.247,unc=\\192.168.1.247\share,vers=2.1,user=domainuser,domain=addomain.local,pass=*******
[713257.116599] CIFS CFS: Send error in SessSetup = -13
[713257.117237] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -13
mount error(13): Permission Denied
refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
-------END VERBOSE OUTPUT-----

Comment: That's the kind of stuff that should be added in the question itself. Feel free to edit it.

Comment: You're, right, my bad, but I gave up out of frustration and just mounted an NFS share instead on a NAS.  I originally wanted it on a Windows server because it would have made a restore of the backup being stored in the remote location easier should it ever be required, but at least its being stored somewhere other than the appliance the back up is of, setting up access shouldn't be to difficult if its ever required, just more steps than if it was on Windows.  Thank you for responding to my question.